# How to make a dependency to the latest version of boost?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dependencies, packaging

I'm packaging a couple of libraries that have some dependencies with one-another.

To simplify, let's say I have: libA and libB.

libB depends on libA for both building and installing.

libA depends on `libboost-system-dev (>= 1.49)` for building, and `libboost-system (>= 1.49)` for installing.

libA's package builds successfully using cowbuilder but when trying to build libB's package, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libA1 : Depends: libboost-system (>= 1.49) which is a virtual package.
Unable to resolve dependencies!  Giving up...
```

Obviously, cowbuilder does not know which libboost-system package to install.

I'd like to avoid having to write `libboost-system1.49` in libA's installation dependencies so that it always uses the latest available boost version.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Does this not get taken care of by dpkg-shlibdeps? As per http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#s-dpkg-shlibdeps

Answer (score 0):

`libboost-system1.49.0` is available only for vesions Ubuntu 12.10 or later.[(See this)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&searchon=names&keywords=libboost-system). `liba` avilable for 12.10 is `liba52-0.7.4`. [(see this)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libA). Reason for `libboost-system1.49` is not available may be you are running on a older Ubuntu version.

You can download `libboost-system1.49.0` .deb package for Ubuntu 11.10 from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~cartodb/+archive/gis/+build/4470399/+files/libboost-system1.49.0_1.49.0-2cdb%7Elucid1_amd64.deb)

You can also download `libboost-system1.49.0` .deb package for Ubuntu 12.04 from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/boost/+build/3978677/+files/libboost-system1.49.0_1.49.0-3.1ubuntu1irie1%7Eprecise1_amd64.deb)